# Cannot extend python IntEnum with a Mixin class

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

EDIT: it turns out this was just a bug that has been fixed as of 3.7.1.

If I create a mixin class and try to add it to add it to an `IntEnum`, I get this error:

```py
>>> from enum import IntEnum
>>> class Mixin:
...  pass
...
>>> class C(Mixin, IntEnum):
...  A=1
...  B=2
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\enum.py", line 211, in __new__
    enum_member = __new__(enum_class)
TypeError: object.__new__(C) is not safe, use int.__new__()
```

This doesn't work, either (same error):

```py
from enum import IntEnum

class M: ...

class C(M, IntEnum): ...

class D(C):
 A=1
 B=2
```

The [docs seem to indicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing) that this should be possible, and it does work for a regular `Enum`:

```py
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Mixin:
...  pass
...
>>> class D(Mixin, Enum):
...  A=1
...  B=2
...
>>>
```

Not sure if this is a bug or a limitation of `IntEnum`. What is going on here?

Comment: Your first code works fine when I try it. Python 3.7.2

Comment: `Enum` is somewhat weird; it abuses metaclasses in order to "hijack" the `class` statement to define something with decidedly non-class-like semantics.

Comment: @khelwood it does not work in 3.7.0. i'll have to try it in 3.7.2.

Comment: It worked in Python 3.7.1 as well.

Comment: This perhaps: https://bugs.python.org/issue29577

Comment: @khelwood working in the latest 3.7.3. i guess this is a bug that has already been fixed. nothing to see here, move along.

Comment: Problem was caused by a bug that has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed since Python 3.7.1.